# cordova-plugin-bluetoothle initialize method not working in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

For some reason, initialize method does not work

```
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public platform: Platform,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(
      () => {
        let initializeResult: object;
        let params: object = {
          "request": true,
          "statusReceiver": false,
          "restoreKey": "bluetoothleplugin"
        }
        console.log('Im ready3x');
        cordova.plugins.bluetoothle.initialize(initializeResult, params).then(
          (success) =>{
            this.toastInitialize('Im ready3x');
          },
          (error) =>{
            this.toastInitialize('Not ready3x');
          }
        );
        //this.toastInitialize('Im ready3x');
        let enableSuccess: object; 
        let enableError: object;
        cordova.plugins.bluetoothle.enable(enableSuccess, enableError);
        this.toastInitialize('enabled');
      }
    );

  }
```

What could have gone wrong? The app starts but no toast is seen. Tested on a real device that previously was able to scan using a plugin(ionic native ble)